# How to place output of python script compiling latex document at desired location using "execute_process" command of cmake?

Tags: python, cmake

I have a cmake file from which i am executing a python script using "execute_command" as follows:

```
execute_process (COMMAND C:/Programs/Python27/python.exe "C:/packaging/doc/release_doc.py" 
--var_ProjectName "${TARGET}" 
--var_version "${_VERSION}" OUTPUT_FILE  "C:/packaging/doc/")
```

When the cmake is executed i am not getting the output at the location specified inside "OUTPUT_FILE". The python file which i am executing is actually compiling a latex .tex file and hence generating a the corresponding pdf document along with the .log file, .aux file and .out file.

When i execute the python script from the location where the latex .tex document is located i get all the files generated at the same location and pdf is all alligned but when i have to execute the same python script from the cmake i am getting all the four files placed at the location different from .tex document and the pdf file alignment gets distrupted.

So, please suggest how can i have the this python file executed from within the cmake  and the output of files at the location as i desire.

Answer (score 0):

Is "C:/packaging/doc/" a folder? Then please replace it by something like "C:/packaging/doc/output.txt".

you can also try using OUTPUT_VARIABLE and check if it makes any difference:

```
 
    execute_process (COMMAND COMMAND C:/Programs/Python27/python.exe "C:/packaging/doc/release_doc.py" --var_ProjectName "${TARGET}" --var_version "${_VERSION}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE test)
    message(${test})
    file(WRITE "C:/packaging/doc/output2.txt" "${test}")
```

Comment: actually the script which i am executing is compiling a latex file. So during compilation four files are generated as output.aux, output.log, output.out,output.pdf and all needs to be created at one location so how these three files to be created at same location.